# Getting "error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, sdl

I have SDL, SDL image with png libraries working fine. I have a small game I'm making and it runs well on my windows 10 machine and my raspberry pi.  Yesterday I started adding sound effects and music on my windows box. Everything working just fine.  I port the code over to my pi and I'm getting this error when trying to run now:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory .
```

To me this makes no sense because I am linking with -lSDL2_mixer and I have all the required files in /usr/local/lib, where all of my other SDL libraries are (and all the others are being found just fine by my system).

The files that got installed in /usr/local/lib after my make install command were:

```
libSDL2_mixer.a
libSDL2_mixer.la
libSDL2_mixer.so
libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0
libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0.2.2
```

Again this all looks good to me. I also tried copying those files to a separate folder and made sure I was including that folder in my execution command, still got the same error.  Anyone have any tips they can share?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out maybe 10 minutes after posting this.

I was searching apt-cache for other mixer packages out there and found "libsdl2mixer-2.0-0", which I thought I already had? but guess not. I installed that and everything works now.

Hope this helps someone.